# Maximizing Mixing Proportions

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

In this [articel](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304407622001841), I am trying to figure out how the authors arrived at $\hat{\pi}_k$. I am just stuck, and I appriciate any help.

Here is the problem:

$$Q_{1}(\gamma , \pi; \theta^{(m)}) = 
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{k=1}^{K} z^{(m)}_{ik} \log(\pi_k) - n\gamma \sum_{k=1}^{K} [\log (\epsilon + \pi_k) - \log(\epsilon)]$$

The mixing proportions are updated by maximizing the equation above with respect to the mixing proportions $\mathbf{\pi}$ subject to the constraint $\sum_{k=1}^{K} \pi_k = 1$. Hence, we introduce a Lagrange multiplier $\alpha$ to take into account the constraint and aim to solve the following set of equations:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \pi_k} \left[ \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{k=1}^{K} z^{(m)}_{ik} \log(\pi_k) - n {\gamma} \sum_{k=1}^{K}  \log\left(\epsilon+\pi_{k}\right)- \alpha \left( \sum_{k=1}^{K} \pi_k - 1 \right) \right] = 0.$$

Given that $\epsilon$ is very close to zero, a straightforward calculation gives
$$\hat{\pi}_k = \max \left\{ 0, \frac{1}{1 - K\gamma} \left[ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} z_{ik}^{(m)} - \gamma \right] \right\}.$$

**Update: Based on @Tony Mathew's comment (Thank you! )**

Given the Lagrangian:
$$
\mathcal{L} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{k=1}^{K} z^{(m)}_{ik} \log(\pi_k) - n\gamma \sum_{k=1}^{K} \log(\epsilon + \pi_k) - \alpha \left( \sum_{k=1}^{K} \pi_k - 1 \right)
$$

We need to find:
$$
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \pi_j} = \frac{\partial}{\partial \pi_j} \left[ \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{k=1}^{K} z^{(m)}_{ik} \log(\pi_k) - n\gamma \sum_{k=1}^{K} \log(\epsilon + \pi_k) - \alpha \left( \sum_{k=1}^{K} \pi_k - 1 \right) \right]
$$

for each $j$ from $1$ to $K$.

1. Differentiate the first term:
   $$
      \frac{\partial}{\partial \pi_j} \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{k=1}^{K} z^{(m)}_{ik} \log(\pi_k) \right) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} z^{(m)}_{ij} \frac{1}{\pi_j}
   $$
2. Differentiate the second term:
   $$
      -n\gamma \frac{\partial}{\partial \pi_j} \left( \sum_{k=1}^{K} \log(\epsilon + \pi_k) \right) = -n\gamma \frac{1}{\epsilon + \pi_j}
    $$
   since $\epsilon$ is close to $0$, then it becomes $-n\gamma \frac{1}{\pi_j}$
3. Differentiate the third term:
   $$
      -\alpha \frac{\partial}{\partial \pi_j} \left( \sum_{k=1}^{K} \pi_k - 1 \right) = -\alpha
      $$

Combining these, we get:
$$
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \pi_j} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} z^{(m)}_{ij} \frac{1}{\pi_j} - n\gamma \frac{1}{\pi_j} - \alpha = 0
$$

This equation must be solved for each $j$ from 1 to $K$. But I still do not see how they will end up as the equation in the article, given what I did above is correct.

Comment: This makes no sense. You're differentiating with respect to $\pi_k$, but $k$ is a dummy summation index.

Comment: @joriki would you please show me how should I approach it. Thank you!

Comment: Instead of $\frac{\partial}{\partial \pi_k}$, do $\frac{\partial}{\partial \pi_j}$ with $\frac{\partial \pi_k}{\partial \pi_j} = \delta_{jk} = \begin{cases} 0, \quad \text{if } j \neq k \\ 1, \quad \text{if } j = k\end{cases}$. Varying $j$ from $1$ to $K$, you'll get $K$ equations. You should be able to rearrange them to get $\pi_k$ as a function of $\alpha$ and the other parameters. Then the $K+1^{\text{th}}$ comes from using $\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha}$. Substitute the $\pi_k$ functions here to get a single equation in $\alpha$, solve for $\alpha$, substitute in the $\pi_k$ functions.

Comment: @TonyMathew Thank you! Would you check my updated work and give me further hints on how to approach it?

Comment: Looks good so far. You can rearrange the last equation into $\pi_j = ...$. Then we know from the constraint that $\sum_j \pi_j = 1$. Substituting for $\pi$, you'll get a single equation in terms of unknown $\alpha$. Hopefully you can solve for $\alpha$ from that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From

$$
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \pi_j} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} z^{(m)}_{ij} \frac{1}{\pi_j} - n\gamma \frac{1}{\pi_j} - \alpha = 0
$$

multiplying by $\pi_j$ we have

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} z^{(m)}_{ij} - n\gamma - \alpha\pi_j = 0
$$

now summing up $j$

$$
\sum_{j=1}^K\sum_{i=1}^{n} z^{(m)}_{ij} - n\gamma K - \alpha = 0 \Rightarrow \alpha = \sum_{j=1}^K\sum_{i=1}^{n} z^{(m)}_{ij} - n\gamma K
$$

and finally

$$
\pi_j = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} z^{(m)}_{ij}-n\gamma}{\sum_{j=1}^K\sum_{i=1}^{n} z^{(m)}_{ij} - n\gamma K}
$$

Comment: Since $\sum_{j=1}^K\sum_{i=1}^{n} z^{(m)}_{ij}=n$, then $\pi_j = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} z^{(m)}_{ij}-n\gamma}{n - n\gamma K}$ as it is above. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: would you take a look at this one https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4845212/gaussian-mixture-model-with-penalty please