# Gaussian mixture model with penalty

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

In this [article](https://www3.stat.sinica.edu.tw/sstest/j27n1/J27N17/J27N17.html) it is written as follow:

Given the current estimate
$(\hat{\pi}_{1}^{(0)},\ldots,\hat{\pi}_{M}^{(0)})$ for $\pi$, to solve
\begin{equation*} \frac{\partial}{\partial \pi_m} \left[ \sum_{i=1}^n
 \sum_{m=1}^M h_{im} \log \pi_m - n\lambda D_{f} \sum_{m=1}^M
 \log(\epsilon + p_{\lambda}({\pi}_m)) - \beta\left(\sum_{m=1}^M \pi_m
 - 1\right) \right] = 0, \end{equation*}

where $p_{\lambda}(\cdot)$ is the SCAD penalty

we substitute $\log(\epsilon + p_{\lambda}(\hat{\pi}_m))$ by its linear approximation $$\log(\epsilon
 + p_{\lambda}(\hat{\pi}^{(0)}_m) + \left(\frac{p'_{\lambda}(\hat{\pi}_m^{(0)})}{\epsilon +
 p_{\lambda}(\hat{\pi}^{(0)}_m)}\right)\left(\hat{\pi}_{m}-\hat{\pi}^{(0)}_{m}
 \right)$$

By setting $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{m=1}^M h_{im} = n$, we first update the value of
$\beta$ by \begin{equation*} \beta = n - n\lambda D_{f} \sum_{m=1}^M
 \frac{p_{\lambda}(\hat{\pi}^{(0)}_m) \hat{\pi}^{(0)}_{m}}{\epsilon +
 p_{\lambda}(\hat{\pi}^{(0)}_m)}. \end{equation*}

Now, if I follow what is above, then I have:

\begin{equation*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \pi_m} \left[ \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{m=1}^M h_{im} \log \pi_m - n\lambda D_{f} \sum_{m=1}^M \left[\log(\epsilon + p_{\lambda}(\hat{\pi}^{(0)}_m) + \left(\frac{p'_{\lambda}(\hat{\pi}_m^{(0)})}{\epsilon + p_{\lambda}(\hat{\pi}^{(0)}_m)}\right)\left(\hat{\pi}_{m}-\hat{\pi}^{(0)}_{m} \right) \right] - \beta\left(\sum_{m=1}^M \pi_m - 1\right) \right] = 0,
\end{equation*}
$$
\frac{\partial \ell_P}{\partial \pi_j} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} h_{ij} \frac{1}{\pi_j} - n \lambda D_{f} \left(\frac{p'_{\lambda}(\hat{\pi}_j^{(0)})}{\epsilon + p_{\lambda}(\hat{\pi}^{(0)}_j)}\right)-\beta
$$
However, after taking the sum of over $j=1, \ldots,M$ and using the constraint $\sum_{m=1}^{M} \pi_{m}=1$, **I do not see where** $\hat{\pi}^{(0)}_{m}$ come from in $\beta$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \pi_m} \left[ \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{m=1}^M h_{im} \left[\log (\hat{\pi}^{(0)}_m)+\frac{1}{\hat{\pi}^{(0)}_m}\left(\pi_m-\hat{\pi}^{(0)}_m\right)\right] - n\lambda D_{f} \sum_{m=1}^M \left[\log(\epsilon + p_{\lambda}(\hat{\pi}^{(0)}_m) + \left(\frac{p'_{\lambda}(\hat{\pi}_m^{(0)})}{\epsilon + p_{\lambda}(\hat{\pi}^{(0)}_m)}\right)\left(\hat{\pi}_{m}-\hat{\pi}^{(0)}_{m} \right) \right] - \beta\left(\sum_{m=1}^M \pi_m - 1\right) \right] = 0,
$$

we have

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n h_{im}\frac{1}{\hat{\pi}^{(0)}_m}-n\lambda D_f\left(\frac{p'_{\lambda}(\hat{\pi}_m^{(0)})}{\epsilon + p_{\lambda}(\hat{\pi}^{(0)}_m)}\right)-\beta=0
$$

now summing up $m$

$$
\sum_{m=1}^M\sum_{i=1}^n h_{im}-n\lambda D_f\sum_{m=1}^M\left(\frac{p'_{\lambda}(\hat{\pi}_m^{(0)})}{\epsilon + p_{\lambda}(\hat{\pi}^{(0)}_m)}\right)\hat{\pi}^{(0)}_m-\beta\sum_{m=1}^M\hat{\pi}^{(0)}_m = 0
$$

or

$$
n - n\lambda D_f\sum_{m=1}^M\frac{p'_{\lambda}(\hat{\pi}_m^{(0)})\hat{\pi}^{(0)}_m}{\epsilon + p_{\lambda}(\hat{\pi}^{(0)}_m)}-\beta=0
$$